# Can I submit an app supporting iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, ios7

Recently I tried to upload my app that supports iOS 7, but iTunes Connect rejected that. So, I tried to change the supported version to iOS 8.0+, it worked.

Is iOS 7 dead? I need to support version 7.0.

Could you help me?

Comment: Also make sure you use APIs supported in iOS7. You can't use the new APIs in iOS 8 unless you enclose them in a conditional test that tests the user is running iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support iOS 7 users, you can set the minimum deployment target to iOS 7. You need to take great care though that iOS 7 users aren't executing iOS 8 code. [You should read up on Configuring a Project for SDK-based development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html).

FWIW, [82% of users right now are using iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "yes".  My app supports iOS 7.0 and up at the moment, no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can support ios 7. You have to set your architecture for both 32 bit and 64 bit and you need to take care of your code. You code should work on both os. Apple has changed many classes for ios 8. Set your build architecture and your minimum deployment target.